# Compress an uncompressed xlsx file using node.js (Electron)

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an unzipped xlsx file, in it I edit some files to be able to generate a new xlsx file containing new data.
In linux to recompress the file in xlsx I just need to go into the terminal and type

`find . -type f | xargs zip ../newfile.xlsx`

into the folder where the xlsx files are.
The question now is how can I do this using node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to compress a direct list of files contained in xlsx, for some reason if we try to compress the folder the file has corrupted.

The code looks like this if you use JSZIP

```
var fs = require('fs');
var JSZip = require("jszip");
var zip = new JSZip();
var file = [];
file.push("_rels/.rels");
file.push("docProps/core.xml");
file.push("docProps/app.xml");
file.push("docProps/custom.xml");
file.push("[Content_Types].xml");
file.push("xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/styles.xml");
file.push("xl/pivotTables/_rels/pivotTable3.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/pivotTables/_rels/pivotTable1.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/pivotTables/_rels/pivotTable2.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/pivotTables/pivotTable3.xml");
file.push("xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml");
file.push("xl/pivotTables/pivotTable2.xml");
file.push("xl/workbook.xml");
file.push("xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet3.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml");
file.push("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
file.push("xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml");
file.push("xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml");
file.push("xl/sharedStrings.xml");
file.push("xl/pivotCache/_rels/pivotCacheDefinition1.xml.rels");
file.push("xl/pivotCache/pivotCacheDefinition1.xml");
file.push("xl/pivotCache/pivotCacheRecords1.xml");

for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
  zip.file(file[i], fs.readFileSync("/home/user/xlsx_FILES/"+file[i]));
}

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
  // see FileSaver.js
  saveAs(content, "yourfile.xlsx");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver), a compression library for nodejs. The [docs](https://archiverjs.com/docs/) for the library look like they are comprehensive.  The library also allows you to append archives and take advantage of streaming api's for appending and creating new archives.

Here is an example snippet from their docs which shows how to use the library.

```js
// require modules
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');

// create a file to stream archive data to.
var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip', {
    store: true // Sets the compression method to STORE.
});

// listen for all archive data to be written
output.on('close', function() {
  console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
  console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

// good practice to catch this error explicitly
archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the file
archive.pipe(output);
```

Comment: It works well for mass compression, but when trying to compress back to xlsx the file gets corrupted.

Comment: I found the solution, I just posted it as an answer